# Responding to UIAlertViewDelegate in a category

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uialertview, objective-c-category

I have a simple class like this

.h

```
@interface DJMyClass : NSObject
+ (void)someFunction;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "DJJavaFunction+UIAlert.h"

@interface DJMyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* someString;
@end
@implementation DJMyClass
+(void)functionWithName:(NSString *)functionName
                 callbackId:(int)callbackId
                       args:(NSArray *)args
{
    DJMyClass *newFunction = [[DJMyClass alloc] init];
    newFunction.function = functionName;
    newFunction.callbackId = callbackId;
    newFunction.args = args;

    [newFunction processFunction];
}
- (void)processFunction
{
  [self showAlertWithTitle:title message:message buttons:buttons inputField:inputField callbackId:_callbackId];
}
@end
```

Now I have created different extensions of this class, which I import and use within this class.

.h

```
@interface DJMyClass (UIAlert) <UIAlertViewDelegate>

- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                   message:(NSString *)message
                   buttons:(NSArray *)buttons
                inputField:(NSDictionary *)inputField
                callbackId:(int)callbackId;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation DJJavaFunction (UIAlert)

- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                   message:(NSString *)message
                   buttons:(NSArray *)buttons
                inputField:(NSDictionary *)inputField
                callbackId:(int)callbackId
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        // Add the buttons
        for (NSString *btn in buttons)
        {
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:btn];
        }

        // Add text field
        if (!inputField)
        {
            alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
        }
        else
        {
            alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

            UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
            textField.placeholder = inputField[@"placeholder"];
            textField.text = inputField[@"text"];
        }

        alert.delegate = self;
        alert.tag = 44;
        [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

This all works well, except that the UIAlertViewDelegate methods are never called.
Is it even possible to respond to UIAlertViewDelegate calls from within a category?

Thanks

Comment: You have mistake in your code. How does it even compile. + someFunction is a class method which calls instance method on self.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really make sense to set the delegate to the object that calls the delegate. Where do you even declare you implement that protocol ? You should probably subclass, and consider using UIAlertController since UIAlertView is deprecated.

Comment: The error probably with the code is that you are showing the alertview inside class method and setting the delegate to class which will not trigger UIAlertViewDelegate methods which are all instance methods, until and unless you create an instance of the class.

Comment: My apologies. I simplified my code for the sake of the question. I've edited it above to show that I do in fact call the showAlert method on an instance not the class. Also, I am trying to make it work back to iOS 6 so using both `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertController`.

Comment: I think i've found the problem. My UIAlert category is dealloc'd as soon as the alert is shown.